# Jquery: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

El navegador me devuelve el error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined con el siguiente script.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    (function($) {
           "use strict";

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value)
    }, "type the correct answer -_-");

    // validate contactForm form
    $(function() {
        $('#contactForm').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                number: {
                    required: false,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "come on, you have a name, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "come on, you have a subject, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your subject must consist of at least 4 characters"
                },
                number: {
                    required: "come on, you have a number, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your Number must consist of at least 5 characters"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "no email, no message"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.",
                    minlength: "thats all? really?"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    type:"POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    url:"/assets/contact_process.php",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                            $('#success').fadeIn();
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                   $('#success').modal('show');
                        })
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $('#error').fadeIn();
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                   $('#error').modal('show');
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
 })(jQuery)
})
```

Comment: ¿Estás incluyendo la librería jQuery correctamente antes de usar tu código?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ese era el error, inluía la librería después de incluir el script. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` es el equivalente de `jQuery`.

El mensaje:

> `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

indica por tanto que la librería jQuery no existe, sea porque estás usando código jQuery sin haber incluido la librería jQuery antes, porque estás usando una URL incorrecta para incluir la librería o por otro motivo.

Por ejemplo, cuando usas un script con código jQuery en el `body` e incluyes la librería en el `footer`, te va a dar ese error, porque la librería se carga después.  Por este motivo, la librería jQuery suele incluirse en el `head` del DOM, de modo que ésta esté disponible desde el principio.