# Error al pasar el id del input a una funcion de javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, razor

Tengo un input text donde figura el precio con coma decimal. Tengo una `función loadPriceWithDecimalDot(idInput)` dodne quiero que se ejecute al cargarse la pagina. La funcion esta en un archivo llamado funciones.js, donde quiero pasarle como argumento/parametro el id del input, para que cambie en el precio la coma por el punto decimal.

Aca la `funcion function loadPriceWithDecimalDot(idInput)`  pero la consola muestra el siguiente error:

**funciones.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at loadPriceWithDecimalDot (funciones.js:5)**

```js
function loadPriceWithDecimalDot(idInput) {

    var getprice = $('#'+ idInput).val();
    //si es num decimal, cambio la coma ","por el punto "." para poder hacer el calculo
    var price = parseFloat(getprice.replace(/,/g, "."));
    $('#' + idInput).val(price)
}
```

aca llamo a la funcion

```js
 loadPriceWithDecimalDot(txt_price)
```

aca el input

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_price" name="txt_price" maxlength="10" value="@Model.Precio" required />
```

aca llamo a la funcion cuando carga la pagina

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", loadPricewithDecimalDot(), false);
</script>
```

Comment: Ese error ocurre cuando intentas usar código jQuery sin haber incluido primero la librería jQuery en ese contexto. Por lo general, si vas a usar jQuery, debes incluirla al principio, en el `head`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Jquery: ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175832/jquery-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Gracias @ A. Cedano, es que en el loyout tengo la llamada al  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") deberia incluirme jquery

Comment: Esa llamada debe ser previa a todo código jQuery. Si lo tienes así, entonces revisa lo que hace `@Scripts.Render`, o si la URL de la biblioteca jQuery es correcta. Lo cierto es que ese error ocurre porque jQuery no está incluida al momento de querer usar código propio suyo como este: `var getprice = $('#'+ idInput).val();` o cualquier otro que tenga `$`

Comment: si incluyo jquery en el head me sigue tirando el mismo error. Entonces lo incluí directamente en la pagina haciendo <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
    window.addEventListener("load", loadPricewithDecimalDot(), false);
</script>

Comment: de esta forma la consola no tira mas el error, pero la función no funciona

Comment: Entonces debes revisar ahora por qué no funciona, haciendo pruebas de consola. Una cosa, pon siempre la URL completa cuando incluyas librerías, y usa una versión reciente de jQuery, la versión `1.8` es prehistórica. La última versión es esta: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: gracias por la version! googlee y pegue la que vi primero para chequear!

Comment: En tu código no explicas de qué modo llamas  `loadPriceWithDecimalDot()`, convendría que expliques el contexto para poder ayudarte mejor. Generalmente el `input` tendría un listener para escuchar los cambios en el mismo y lanzar la función, pero tampoco se sabe lo que quieres hacer con ese valor. Incluso se podría forzar a que el input sólo acepte valores decimales, así evitas que se escriban letras u otras cosas.

Comment: [Mira aquí un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320458/5587982) donde ya, de entrada, en el `input` sólo puedes escribir decimales con punto, así ya estableces un control que descarga el código de comprobaciones posteriores sujetas a posibles errores y de paso educas al usuario sobre el modo de usar el programa que estás escribiendo.

Comment: Gracias voy a mirar el ejemplo. si me olvide de poner que a la función la llamo con window.addEventListener("load", loadPricewithDecimalDot(), false); ahora lo agrego a mi publicación.

Comment: Creo que le estás dando muchas vueltas al tema, para dar formato puedes hacerlo desde el backend :)

Comment: gracias @fredyfx! tenes razón, mas facil reemplazar el punto por la coma haciendo un Replace desde el lado backend por ejemplo: string price = Convert.ToString(Model.Precio);    price = price.Replace(',', '.');

Comment: Desde el modelo usando DataAnnotations también es una alternativa :D