# (Jquery) Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at host.js:4`

este error porque me da. Porque no reconoce el símbolo $ ? estoy usando VSCODE.

me refiero a que antes del $ no hay ningún otra linea de código solo esta así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Revisa los **js** que cargas; antes de usar el **$** debe cargarse el js del **jQuery**.

Comment: si y me sigue dando el error. no hay nada antes del $

Comment: en el archivo html lo estoy llamando así **<script src="/static/JS/host.js"></script>**    aquí al Jquery **<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"</script>**

Comment: ya actualize mi comentario y puse la llamada del Jquery. lo que yo pienso es que el problema esta relacionado con que el editor no reconoce el $ porque en IntelliJ tengo entendido que si vas a configuraciones  librereria y framework > Javascript y agregas la librería Jquery para que te reconozca los símbolos $ como que estas usando Jquery . pero en Visual Code Studio no veo algo parecido en configuraciones y entonces no se que hacer ahi. he buscado en otros lados pero las  opciones que yo vi no me funcionaron @BetaM

Comment: eso cierto no me había dado cuenta del orden. puedes publicar la respuesta para ponerle el ganchito. Gracias

Comment: primeramente debes de agregar la url de jquery antes de realizar consultas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Jquery: ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175832/jquery-referenceerror-is-not-defined)