# Obtener URL en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buenas estoy intentando obtener una URL (de una hoja de calculo de Google), pero me da un error que dice que "$" no está definido (linea 1), el código es el siguiente:

```
 $.get( "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SObxQAY7DG1LHthOy7Fz-t2y7Za7tHb0JuBWSwfu2ls/edit#gid=0", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Cabe aclarar que la idea sería además que la info que está en dicha hoja de calculo la debe convertir a formato XML

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Jquery: ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175832/jquery-referenceerror-is-not-defined) ... Tienes que incluir la librería jQuery en el `head` de tu HTML para poder usarla. Este es el código de inclusión: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Si te dice que $ no esta definido, seguramente es que no has añadido bien el JQuery. Si aun no lo has descargado, puedes obtenerlo de acá: https://jquery.com/download/

Asegurate de añadirlo correctamente. Mas info por aca: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: En que parte de mi código incluyo el jQuery?